# Lock leaf particles to specific axis?

Tags: particles

My goal is to make a weeping willow tree, so I'm using a particle system for the leaves, which are long strands hanging towards the ground. I want to make it so the rotation in the z axis is random with little to no rotation on the x and y axis, so they always appear to be hanging. How can I achieve this? My settings and results are shown below.  [image: My settings and result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my original answer was wrong. Try experimenting with Orientation Axis and Randomize Phase

[image: orientation axis]

Comment: Elaborate a little, like add curve guide to what?

Comment: Editing orientation axis was definitely the way to go, though my object itself wasn't oriented to work well with that. I think it would work with any Orientation Axis as long as you mess with the orientation of the object itself.